# convert string to object using Moshi

Tags: android, kotlin, moshi

for some reason I want to transform this data class

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Planetary(
    val localDate: LocalDate,
    val title: String,
)
```

and I have created adapter for `LocalDate`

```
class DayAdapter {
@ToJson
fun toJson(date: LocalDate): String = date.toString()

/**
 * Maps the [PlanetaryDto.date] json string to a [LocalDate]
 */
@FromJson
fun fromJson(date: String): LocalDate = LocalDate.parse(date)
}
```

and here is how I try to parcel Planetary to string

```
 val jsonAdapter =  Moshi.Builder().add(DayAdapter())
            .build().adapter(Planetary::class.java).lenient()
        val planetaryJson = jsonAdapter.toJson(planetary)
```

but it gives an error says

> Failed to find the generated JsonAdapter class for class Planetary

Answer (score 0):

Did you add to dependencies(app level):

```
kapt("com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:$moshi_version")
```